# How to replace into a column only if the replacing value is not null?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query that would replace a certain column in the list **only** in case if it is not null. 
For example:

```
replace into upd_services 
select item_id, select (item_desc if is not null), item_list_price  
from upd_services_changes_3 
where item_list_price between 0 and 100;
```

What would be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: This seems a lot like:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233064/mysql-replace-into-with-null.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you would want to evaluate that field for NULL values in a where or in the select list if you had other columns that needed to be updated.

```
replace into upd_services 
select item_id, item_desc, item_list_price  
from upd_services_changes_3 
where item_list_price between 0 and 100
and item_desc is not null;
```

Or possibly:

```
replace into upd_services 
select item_id, ISNULL(a.item_desc, b.item_id), item_list_price  
from upd_services_changes_3 a 
join upd_services b ON a.item_id = b.item_id
where item_list_price between 0 and 100;
```

Comment: The first one is not what I want for sure, because it simply does not update the entire row in case item_desc is null. I still need the other values to be updated.